# $I=(3,x^2+1)$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Then $I$ is a proper ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

This is from an old exam.

Here is the problem.

Let $I=(3,x^2+1)$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Then $I$ is a proper ideal of $Z[x]$

How does one go about showing that this is a proper ideal. Should I consider $Z[x]/I$ and then show that it is neither $Z[x]$ nor $0$ thus showing that $I$ must be a proper ideal or is there some other easier way to proceed?

My attempt: Since $I=\{ 3p(x)+(x^2+1)q(x): p(x), q(x) \in Z[x] \} $ we know that the constant term of $f(0)$ of any element $f(x) \in I$ must be of the form $3n+m$ for $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Does this help me in anyway?. Am I making this too complicated than it should be?

Can you kindly help?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: one way would be to show that $1 \notin I$.

Comment: Another way would be to use $R/I \cong (R/J)/(I/J)$ when $J \subset I$ are ideals. Choose $J = (3)$ for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $1$ were of the form $3p(x) + (x^2+1)q(x)$, then plugging in $x=i$, you'd get $p(i) = 1/3$, but $p(i)$ must be of the form $a+bi$ with $a$ and $b$ integers.

Comment: Oh okay. Is it because $ \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1) \cong \mathbb{Z}[i]$ and this implies that the realationship $1=3p(x)+(x^2+1)q(x)$ taken in the ring of Gaussian integers we get $p(i)=1/3$?

Comment: Well, that almost works, except what do you mean by $1/3$ if you are working in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? You could switch to $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and your explanation would be correct, but a more down-to-earth way is to really just plug in $x=i$ into the equality $3p(x) + (x^2+1)q(x)=1$ of polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x]$.

Comment: Ok I get it now. $p$ was a polynomial with integer coefficients to begin with. So $p(i)=1/3$ is indeed a contradiction. :)

Answer (score 6):

Boring way: show that a single element, say 1, is not in your ideal.  Do this by contradiction --- what can you say about p(x) and q(x) if 1 is in $I$?

Fun way:  set $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$, and show that

1)  R is isomorphic to the ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, and

2) the quotient $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(3)$

Then use your favorite method to show that $3$ is not a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, so generates a proper ideal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you explain a bit more. If $1\in I$ then one of $p$ or $q$ has to be zero right?. Also, how does showing that $(3)$ is a proper ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ help show that $(3,x^2+1)$ is a proper ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?. I am sorry if my questions are stupid. I really struggle when an ideal is generated by two elements :(

Answer (score 2):

How far are you with the ring isomorphism theorems to show that $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(3, X^2+1) \cong \mathbb{F}_{3^2} $? Hint: $X^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{3}$.

Comment: There is no need for such an isomorphism to be established: it is enough to show that there is a ring map $\mathbb Z[X]\to\mathbb F_{9}$ which maps $3$ and $X^2+1$ to zero (and $1$ to $1$, of course)

Comment: I actually showed that $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(3, X^2+1) \cong \mathbb{F}_{3^2}$ using the second isomorphism theorem and showed that result is indeed a field with $3^2$ elements. But is there a way to show that $1\notin I$. That somehow seems so much more simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The field $\mathbb F_9$ has a square root of $-1$. Let us call it $i$.

There is a unique map $f:\mathbb Z[X]\to \mathbb F_9$ such that $f(p)=p(i)$ for all $p\in \mathbb Z[X]$. This is very easy to see that this is in fact a homomorphism of rings.

It is clear that $f(3)=0$ and $f(X^2+1)=0$. Since $f$ is a map of rings, it follows that the whole ideal $I$ generated by $3$ and by $X^2+1$ in $\mathbb Z[X]$ is contained in the kernel of $f$.

Now obviously $f(1)=1\neq0$, so $1\in \mathbb Z[X]$ is not contained in the kernel of $f$ and, a fortiori, it is also not contained in the ideal $I$.

Answer (score 0):

Reformulating Barry's answer in a possibly more down to Earth way:

All the polynomials $p(x)$ in your ideal have the property that $p(i)$ is divisible by three in the ring of Gaussian integers. It is easy to show that polynomials with that property form an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. It is also easy to give an example of a polynomial that does not have this property, so $I$ is proper.